# "sendmessage" is undefined in server after deploying(chrome.runtime.sendmessage)

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, angular8

Am trying to know whether my chrome extension is installed or not from my web app.

here is my web app code,

```
declare var chrome;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {

  checkChromeExtenstion(){
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage("dnjagggnhjnlhihfgnfcfbbhghjibjca", { message: "isinstalled" }, (response) => {
  console.log(response);
  if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {

   this.chromeData = {
     "chrome_status":"Uninstalled"
   }

  }
  else{

    this.chromeData = {
      "chrome_status":"Installed"
    }
  }
});

}

}
```

Working fine in local. am getting response from my extension. But when i  deploy in development server.. throwing error in chrome console

```
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined
    at DashboardComponent.checkChromeExtenstion (dashboard.component.ts:9)
```

And in Mozilla,

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: chrome is not defined
```

Please suggest me what should i do to make it work.

Comment: 1) Could be wrong `externally_connectable` configuration in manifest.json 2) I don't know Angular so maybe `declare var chrome` is the wrong thing because it creates a new empty variable that overwrites the built-in global `chrome`.

Comment: Then how come working in local server?